# Stake chart of different man and female alive

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a stake chart of man and women life death and alive chart which has dropdown menu which shows user different alive and death using html css and js but the problem is it showing only same death alive ratio
Here is a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <p> Select an outcome to generate a plot displaying its prevalence by gender and survival status </p>

    <label for="Outcomes"> Select an Outcome: </label>

    <select name="Outcomes" id="outcome">
        <option value="SBP"> SBP </option>
        <option value="weight"> weight </option>
        <option value="ARDS"> ARDS </option>
        <option value="dyspnea"> dyspnea</option>
        <option value="hypoxemia"> hypoxemia</option>
    </select>

    <div id="myDiv">

    </div>

<script>
        const data = [{ "hispanic": 0, "female": 0, "old": 0, "dead": 0, "SBP": 121.487, "weight": 63.4695, "ARDS": 0.0088, "dyspnea": 0.1766, "hypoxemia": 0.0265, "sample": 453 },
        { "hispanic": 1, "female": 0, "old": 0, "dead": 0, "SBP": 121.423, "weight": 63.8618, "ARDS": 0.013, "dyspnea": 0.1591, "hypoxemia": 0.0273, "sample": 3853 },
        { "hispanic": 0, "female": 1, "old": 0, "dead": 0, "SBP": 122.6301, "weight": 74.3693, "ARDS": 0.012, "dyspnea": 0.1687, "hypoxemia": 0.0193, "sample": 415 },
        { "hispanic": 1, "female": 1, "old": 0, "dead": 0, "SBP": 121.3046, "weight": 73.8379, "ARDS": 0.0157, "dyspnea": 0.1568, "hypoxemia": 0.0308, "sample": 3501 },
        { "hispanic": 0, "female": 0, "old": 1, "dead": 0, "SBP": 120.0199, "weight": 75.756, "ARDS": 0.1088, "dyspnea": 0.1497, "hypoxemia": 0.1293, "sample": 147 },
        { "hispanic": 1, "female": 0, "old": 1, "dead": 0, "SBP": 121.0816, "weight": 76.4277, "ARDS": 0.0702, "dyspnea": 0.1758, "hypoxemia": 0.0887, "sample": 1297 },
        { "hispanic": 0, "female": 1, "old": 1, "dead": 0, "SBP": 122.1498, "weight": 90.5307, "ARDS": 0.1128, "dyspnea": 0.1955, "hypoxemia": 0.1128, "sample": 133 },
        { "hispanic": 1, "female": 1, "old": 1, "dead": 0, "SBP": 121.566, "weight": 89.0143, "ARDS": 0.0847, "dyspnea": 0.1437, "hypoxemia": 0.0979, "sample": 1287 },
        { "hispanic": 0, "female": 0, "old": 0, "dead": 1, "SBP": 125.8889, "weight": 81.45, "ARDS": 0, "dyspnea": 0, "hypoxemia": 0, "sample": 2 },
        { "hispanic": 1, "female": 0, "old": 0, "dead": 1, "SBP": 125.0605, "weight": 78.4145, "ARDS": 0.2273, "dyspnea": 0, "hypoxemia": 0.2273, "sample": 22 },
        { "hispanic": 0, "female": 1, "old": 0, "dead": 1, "SBP": 110.8, "weight": 81.265, "ARDS": 0.5, "dyspnea": 0, "hypoxemia": 0.5, "sample": 2 },
        { "hispanic": 1, "female": 1, "old": 0, "dead": 1, "SBP": 120.3677, "weight": 91.3292, "ARDS": 0.3636, "dyspnea": 0, "hypoxemia": 0.3636, "sample": 33 },
        { "hispanic": 0, "female": 0, "old": 1, "dead": 1, "SBP": 116.8989, "weight": 78.9615, "ARDS": 0.2308, "dyspnea": 0, "hypoxemia": 0.2308, "sample": 13 },
        { "hispanic": 1, "female": 0, "old": 1, "dead": 1, "SBP": 124.0749, "weight": 76.1999, "ARDS": 0.2727, "dyspnea": 0, "hypoxemia": 0.2727, "sample": 88 },
        { "hispanic": 0, "female": 1, "old": 1, "dead": 1, "SBP": 121.5481, "weight": 92.5458, "ARDS": 0, "dyspnea": 0, "hypoxemia": 0, "sample": 11 },
        { "hispanic": 1, "female": 1, "old": 1, "dead": 1, "SBP": 122.7266, "weight": 87.6138, "ARDS": 0.283, "dyspnea": 0, "hypoxemia": 0.3019, "sample": 106 }]

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("outcome").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
        }

        function myFunction() {
            var select = document.getElementById("outcome");
            var value = selection.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

            var result = data2.fiter(obj => {
                return obj.outcome == value
            })



            var males_dead_data = data.filter(function (result) {
                return result.dead === 1 && result.female === 1;
            });

            var males_alive_data = data.filter(function (result) {
                return result.dead === 0 && result.female === 1;
            });

            var males_dead_outcome = [];
            var males_alive_outcome = [];
            var males_dead_samp = [];
            var males_alive_samp = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                males_dead_outcome.push(males_dead_data[i].result);
                males_alive_outcome.push(males_alive_data[i].result);
                males_dead_samp.push(males_dead_data[i].sample);
                males_alive_samp.push(males_alive_data[i].sample);
            }



            var females_dead_data = data.filter(function (result) {
                return result.dead === 1 && result.female === 0;
            });

            var females_alive_data = data.filter(function (result) {
                return result.dead === 0 && result.female === 0;
            });

            var females_dead_outcome = [];
            var females_alive_outcome = [];
            var females_dead_samp = [];
            var females_alive_samp = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                females_dead_outcome.push(females_dead_data[i].result);
                females_alive_outcome.push(females_alive_data[i].result);
                females_dead_samp.push(females_dead_data[i].sample);
                females_alive_samp.push(females_alive_data[i].sample);
            }



            function weightedAve(grp_ave, weight) {
                var c = [];
                var d = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < weight.length; i++) {
                    c.push(grp_ave[i] * weight[i]);
                    d = c.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / weight.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
                }
                return d;
            }

            var y1 = weightedAve(males_dead_outcome, males_dead_samp)
            var y2 = weightedAve(males_alive_outcome, males_alive_samp)
            var y3 = weightedAve(females_dead_outcome, females_dead_samp)
            var y4 = weightedAve(females_alive_outcome, females_alive_samp)

            var yValues = new Array(y1, y2, y3, y4)

            var plot = [
                {
                    x: ['Dead Males', 'Alive Males', 'Dead Females', 'Alive Females'],
                    y: yValues,
                    type: 'bar'
                }
            ],
                layout = {
                    title: {
                        text: "Prevalence of by Gender and Survival Status"
                    }
                };

            Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', plot, layout)





    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little big for a comment. Maybe you can improve the question this way.

In your code in `myFunction()` you have a for loop which is just incomplete. Is this a copy&paste error? Do you have the actual code for us?

See this:

```js
  for (var i = 0; i a + b)
     / weight.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
  }
```

- `/ weight.reduce...` by itself is not valid. You should see errors in the browser console. Can you copy those here as well?
- `weight` is not an object here so there can be no `reduce` to call
- The for loop looks like this: `(var i = 0; i a + b)`. What were you trying to loop here?

Above the `for` loop are several variables:

```js
  var males_dead_outcome = [];
  var males_alive_outcome = [];
  var males_dead_samp = [];
  var males_alive_samp = [];
```

These variables are initialized but never used in the function. It seems you have not copied the full source code for us - please share it.

The code below calls `weightedAve()` which does not exist in the shared code. Please add that as well.